Does this edit change the original intent of the post?
I recently suggested this edit to a question about a Google Sheets formula. It was mostly reorganization (I moved the data up a paragraph to make the problem statement clearer), and I also deleted a couple of screenshots that seemed redundant with markdown tables OP provided. I think the only other major change I made was to delete this paragraph, which I saw as too vague to be a meaningful inclusion:

Please note, I've researched this topic and read numerous similar questions and answers across Stack Overflow, Google Support, Formulas blogs, etc. None of the cases seem to match mine. Maybe my search terms are deficient.

The rest of the edit was fairly minor - shortening the title, improving markdown, removing noise, and adding a couple of transitions to improve the question's flow.
The edit received two "reject - deviates from the original intent" votes and one approve vote, so it was rejected. Do you agree that it deviated from the author's original intent? Is there any part of the edit I should've omitted?

Nope, seems you're the victim of inexperienced reviewers.

Your edit suggestion looks fine to me. I amended and approved your edit. I suspect reviewers didn't look quite closely enough to see that some blocks of text were only moved within the post and maybe thought you actually removed the clarifying formula expressions, which, IMHO, clearly would conflict with the author's intent unless they were grossly irrelevant to the issue.

Sometimes a traditional diff is hard to parse in terms of what actually changed, especially when content is moved around a bunch.

You can't win either way. I'm pretty sure it was rejected because it changes a lot so then there is an easy assumption you're rewriting the answer and should have posted your own. But if you had changed less, it might have been rejected for not changing enough. 400 more reputation points, then editing will become more hit than miss.

@Gimby "more hit than miss" - I would say that it's all hit, but you might get hit back.

@KarlKnechtel That's when you graduate to being able to make arbitrary edits, but not be able to unilaterally approve trivial changes made by others.

On the plus side, your edit is now live. I just gave a couple of your answers an upvote to put you closer to the goal

@DannyBeckett Hehe thanks. Don’t trip into serial voting though!

Awfully glad I approved the edit and now stand on the right side of history :-)

RoboReviewers - "Lots of red, lots of green, gotta reject"

@M-- Each reviewer has 700+ reviews. (Not necessarily good reviews.)

@MateenUlhaq I'd rather call people inexperienced than incompetent :)
